A way where to keep and how to copy python files to C# project output directory
I have a C# project which works with python web server, written with FastAPI. Server is a part of C# application, and runs and shuts down by C# app.
I usually work only with C# apps and have no experience in cases, when there are two or more projects in repo, which form one app, but written in different programming languages. So, I'm interested in two things:

Is there any common practice where to keep python files in repo with C# solution (e.g. in C# solution folder or somewhere else)?
How to copy python files into C# project output directory on build? I know about call of "Copy" function in csproj, but maybe there are other approaches available? There is an option in Visual Studio to create Python project (pyproj), and I hoped that it is possible to create a reference from C# project to Python project, to copy python files automatically on build, as it is happens with C# dependencies, but it didn't work for me. Does anyone know if such option available?


You implement a Setup, e.g. usign InnoSetup and distribute the C# binary as well as the Python files if you like. The Setup will copy them to a place where you want them to be, e.g. in the Program Files directory.
For your development environment, you may use a post build step with an (x)copy operation.

This question is similar to: Copy files to output directory using csproj dotnetcore. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Thomas Weller, thank you for your answer, but I'm interested in files distributuion on development stage, before creation installer.

@shingo, yes, I saw the answer you suggested, and I have edited my question, hope it became clearer.

Why are you looking for other approaches?

BTW have you checked isxaker's solution in that question?

I'm looking for other approaches, because copy files is like a last resort, it is applicable for any kind of files, but if it is possible to make it with built-in options, like dependencies between C# project, I would prefer this way.

#if debug myPythonPath="c:\I_don't_want_to_copy_them\" #else myPythonPath=myExePath #endif

Manually adding post-build events to .csproj file can ensure your .py file copied to the output directory:
<Target Name="CopyPythonFiles" AfterTargets="Build">
      <Copy SourceFiles="(yourFileName).py" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" />
</Target>


Is your problem being solved? It is hoped that you can give any feedback. @Timur Fayl
